# Leer archivos CSV y crear sus respectivas tablas en mysql

Tags: java, mysql, csv

Esta es la función de mi botón al cargar múltiples archivos CSV, quisiera saber como implementar la función para que esos archivos puedan generarse en tablas en **`MYSQL`** dentro de una base de datos que ya tengo.

```
private void examinarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();        
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
        chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

        int status = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            DefaultListModel<String> modelList = new DefaultListModel<String>();
            for (File item : chooser.getSelectedFiles()) {
                modelList.addElement(item.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            rutaArchivos.setModel(modelList);
        }

    }
```